# How do i paginate query_posts with numeric pagination?

Tags: query-posts, pagination

I have post type called **blog** and i'm showing posts for the type using `query_posts`, eg.

```
query_posts('post_type=blog');
```

I would like to add pagination for this post type in the following format.

```
[First] [1][2][3][4][5] [Last]
```

Please let me know how can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why was this voted down? Seems like an on-topic question to me.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, read this: http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/right-way-to-use-query_posts.html

Then install this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/